# How to check if extjs checkbox is selected in selenium?

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, checkbox

I'm testing a web application implemented in ExtJs  (partially...), the checkboxes implemented as buttons.
The test written in java using Selenium libraries.

For ckicking on the buttons, I'm using something like:

```
selenium.click("css=input.x-form-field.x-form-checkbox",true);
```

Now I'm trying to get the **state of the checkbox**, if it is checked or not, and i can't figure out how to do that.

Here is the implementation:

```
<td id="checkboxfield-1028-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body x-form-cb-wrap" colspan="3" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
<input id="checkboxfield-1028-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-checkbox" type="button" hidefocus="true" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" style="-moz-user-select: text;">
<label id="checkboxfield-1028-boxLabelEl" class="x-form-cb-label x-form-cb-label-after" for="checkboxfield-1028-inputEl">Active</label>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember ExtJs extactly, but I assume that checked and unchecked are two css classes. Try to find out these classes (inspect the page using Chrome Dev. tools).

Define two WebElements on your page object:

```
@FindBy(cssSelector=".x-form-checkbox.unchecked")
WebElement checked;

@FindBy(cssSelector=".x-form-checkbox.checked")
WebElement unchecked;
```

Then you need to wait until the button is checked or unchecked. This can be done with added this method:

```
protected final void waitForElementPresent(final By by) {
   seleniumContext.getWebDriverWait().until(new ExpectedCondition() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(by);
          return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is i don't have this two classes: x-form-checkbox.unchecked & x-form-checkbox.checked.

Please check the implementation part in the question to see the classes i have.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your using a webdriver so, what you can do is:

```
 isChecked = e.findElement(By.tagName("input")).Selected;
```

or

```
 isChecked = e.findElement(By.Id("checkboxfield-1028-bodyEl")).Selected;
```

That gives you the state.

Are you looking for a JUnit assertion for it?

Comment: ExtJs is generating random ids, so the second solution will not work.

Comment: Actually i didn't used webdriver until now (got the automation project already made this way), trying to apply it on my work from this point and on. I'm trying to do:  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.x-form-field.x- form-checkbox[type=\"button\"]")).isSelected();`
But, it saying that: Fail: Returned node was not an HTML element Please advise, you can find the implementation in the first message.

Comment: Its much easier to find something by ID than by css selector since you can apply the same css class to multiple elements. I would suggest going in and giving the item an Id and then finding an element by ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find checkbox using part of id:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'checkboxfield')]")).isSelected();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i cant use xpath in my case.

 I tried to work with CSS selectors: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.x-form-field.x- form-checkbox[type=\"button\"]")).isSelected();` But, it saying that: Fail: Returned node was not an HTML element. 

Please advise, you can find the implementation in the first message.