# Selenium click() or isSelected() are not executed on RadioButton's input element

Tags: xpath, selenium, click

I have radio buttons that are located inside a table, such as:

```
<tr id="radiofield-1080-inputRow">
  <td class="x-form-item-body" id="radiofield-1080-bodyEl" colspan="3">
    <input type="button" id="radiofield-1080-inputEl" class="x-form-field" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="radiofield-1080-boxLabelEl" class="x-form-cb-label">My Label</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I do find the input element, by the following code:

```
xPath = String.format("//tr/td[contains(@id,'%s')][contains(label,'%s')]/label", xType,      text);
webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
```

but `isSelected()` or `click()` doesn't seem to work on it.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: in your XML code where is `</input>` ? please put it.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used selenium in a while but from a quick google it looks like you should try the isChecked and check/uncheck methods.

Here's the Javadoc but for some reason can't get a decent link, obviously check on the Selenium object.  If you're using a different version or if I misunderstood something sorry.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet problem with locator.

Use any of the below below locators

```
By.cssSelector("input[id*='radiofield-']");

By.id("radiofield-1080-inputEl")

By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(@id,'radiofield-')]/input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the "input" instead of the "label".
xpath of input:

```
"//input[@id='radiofield-1080-inputEl']"
```

If the input id is not always the same, you can try this, the location of input will be based off the label:

```
//label[text()='My Label']/preceding-sibling::input
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.
My finding concluded with the following:
ExtJS implement radiobutton and checkbox as button, therefore the selenium isSelected() is not functioning.
There is a need to implement isSelected(), as suggested at:
[How to check if extjs checkbox is selected in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042121/how-to-check-if-extjs-checkbox-is-selected-in-selenium)

The click() does the work, as it is a button.

Thanks again, Michal